# Remove row with condition in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe such as :

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
G1 0 1
G2 1 0
G3 2 1
G4 2 0
G5 0 2
G6 3 4
```

and I would like to remove row if:

- the sum of Col2 and Col3 is 1
- Col2 or Col3 contain one 0 value.

Here I should get:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
G3 2 1
G6 3 4
```

Comment: This post may help: https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-filter-in-r-a-detailed-introduction-to-the-dplyr-filter-function/

Comment: What class is `Col1`? It looks like a character, not a number. How would you add that with `Col2`?

Comment: How can you compute sum on Col1? It is a character and it should be numeric. Are you trying to do something else. Please clarify.

Comment: oups sorry it was col2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `subset` and include the condition.

```
subset(df, Col2 != 0 & Col3 != 0 & (Col2 + Col3) != (1- Col2))
#In this case this gives the same answer
#subset(df, Col2 != 0 & Col3 != 0)

#  Col1 Col2 Col3
#3   G3    2    1
#6   G6    3    4
```

Or using it in `dplyr::filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(Col2 != 0 & Col3 != 0 & (Col2 + Col3) != (1- Col2))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("G1", "G2", "G3", 
"G4", "G5", "G6"), class = "factor"), Col2 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
0L, 3L), Col3 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```